# Adult pupils with multiplication problems

Tags: technology-in-education, software, multiplication-table

I am trying to help some adults who have not practiced mental arithmetic for decades, but now they have a need for various reasons. I have noticed that they are considerably uneven: $2\times4$, $6\times6$, and $8\times8$ are no problem normally, but for some reason, they are often slow and/or unsure of, for instance, $7\times8$, $3\times9$, $7\times12$, etc.

Are there any known apps or web sites where you can define the multiplications for a certain pupil you observed being slow or unsure? I mean, where you can pick out or choose a specific set of calculations, like "flash cards" and the set time limits for practice of speed and accuracy?

For the purpose we use IPad, and Windows 8 on PC.

Comment: You could use Quizlet and do something like this if you know which calculations you want to give to each student.  Or, and this may be better, the student(s) could create their own Quizlets with all multiplications and then remove cards as they see fit.

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded Quizlet and tried it. First I did not understand at all how to use it, I could not find any help function. But after a while i came to the conclusion that you must create a folder first, then create a "study set" by choosing at title and a Language, and then I managed, after a lot of clicking, to actually create tWo cards and test them. And it worked just fine! Exactly what I wanted! (Is there any help function, only that I did not find it?!)

Comment: After logging on the the Quizlet web site I did find a "Help center". I will check that out!

Answer (score 1):

I am working on an app (iPad/iPhone) that allows students to learn/practice multiplication facts. The app provides a number of interactive learning activities as well as a practice section where students interact with the app using their voice.

We are currently beta testing it so it's not in the App Store yet. Please email me if you'd like to try it out (ogi at keenresearch dot com).

Comment: Most generous offer! I have mailed a confirmation of my interest to your mail address!